# Regex, return first match after specific word / Python

Tags: python, regex

E.G. We have this sentence.

`Sample 987 abc sample 567 xyz, yellow world sample 123`

By using this regex = `sample \d+`

I would like, by using `re.findall()` to get values next to the `sample` which is after word `abc`, which is `sample 567 and sample 123`

I know how to find the value I need, the problem is that I need to use it AFTER a specific word and not sure how to.

P.S. This word can be changed from `abc` to `word` so the result will be `sample 123` and e.t.c....

Comment: Why not simply include the leading word in the regex as well?

Comment: Would it always be possible to distinquish `sample` from `Sample` through the capitalized "S". It looks like that word "abc" will only occur *before* any `sample` with a lower "s". Therefor `\bsample (\d+)` may work?

Comment: @JvdV this is just example, in simplest terms I need that assigned regex will search ONLY after the selected word (the first one)

Comment: @rauberdaniel not sure how to do it and achieve what I need. Return all the values from regext after assigned word and ignore all before this word

Comment: `re.findall(r'\bsample\s*(\d+)', s)`? https://ideone.com/LL8wO9

Comment: Or, `re.findall(r'\bsample\s*(\d+)', s[s.index('abc')+3:])`? See https://ideone.com/K3SvpD

Comment: `re.findall(r'\bsample (\d+)', s[s.find('abc'):])` should work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `sample 123 sample 123 sample 123 sample 123 sample 123 xxxxxxxxxx sample 567 sample 678` So I will need sample after xxxxxx.... which is `sample 567 sample 678`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/I7ICK6, find the index of the string you need to start matching from.

Comment: @anubhava but then you modifying the initial string unless I misunderstood you

Comment: @OksanaOk No there is no modification. `s[s.find('abc'):])` gets substring starting from first instance of `abc` in string `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it looks like the following may work for you:

```
\bsample (\d+)(?!.*\babc\b)
```

This will assure that the word "abc" is **not** following, therefor it does not capture '987' from your sample.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oabfpf/1)

- `\b` - A word-boundary.
- `sample`  - Match "sample " literally.
- `(\d+)` - Capture 1+ digits in a capture group.
- `(?!.*\babc\b)` - Negative lookahead to prevent it be in front of the word "abc".

For example:

```
import re
s = 'sample 987 abc sample 567 xyz, yellow world sample 123'
results = re.findall(r'(?<=\bsample )\d+(?!.*\babc\b)', s)
print(results)
```

Prints:

```
['567', '123']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to limit the regex search to a specific area:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'sample \d+')
start_pos = original_string.index('your_start_word')
matches = pattern.findall(original_string, start_pos)
```